# How can you skip or delete cause of EntityExistsException?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, exception

I read Json file addresses and actors.
Some actors have addresses assigned.
I persist actors and adresses but while I persist actors, assigned adresses are also persisted and when I persist address I get EntityExistsException (because they have the same id). My idea was to catch the exception. I do it but how to "skip" address with id I already have?

```
List<Actors> actorsList = objectMapper.readValue(new File("actors.json"), objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, Actors.class));
List<Address> addressList = objectMapper.readValue(new File("addresses.json"), objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, Address.class));

 try {
                for (int i=0; i < actorsList.size(); i++) {
                    Actors actors=actorsList.get(i);
                    entityManager.persist(actors);
                    System.out.println(actors);
                }
                for (int i=0; i < addressList.size(); i++) {
                    Address address=addressList.get(i);
                    entityManager.persist(address);
                    System.out.println(address);
                }
catch(EntityExistsException e){ 

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can try to search them in the database first and if they don't exist, then you can persist them in the database. So for example you can do something like:

```
if(entityManager.findOne(actor.getId()).orElse(null) == null) //if it doesn't exist, then it returns null
   entityManager.persist(actor);
```